# probability that total life of 40 batteries exceeds 1700

Tags: probability, probability-limit-theorems

Each of the batteries in a collection of 40 batteries is equally likely
to be either a type $A$ or a type $B$ battery. Type $A$ batteries last for an amount
of time that has mean $50$ and standard deviation $15$; type $B$ batteries last for
an amount of time that has mean $30$ and standard deviation $6$.

**Question** - Approximate the probability that the total life of all $40$ batteries exceeds $1700$.

**Edited answer**

Let Y be the type of battery, where $Y = 1$ for Type $A$ battery and $Y =2$ for Type $B$ battery.

$E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]  = E[X|Y=1]P[Y=1] + E[X|Y=2]P[Y=2] = (50*0.5) + (30*0.5) = 40$

$Var[X] =E[X^2] - [E[X]]^2$

Hence, we need to find $E[X^2]$,   $E[X^2] = E[E[X^2|Y]]  = E[X^2|Y=1]P[Y=1] + E[X^2|Y=2]P[Y=2] = (15^2+50^2)(0.5)+(30^2+6^2)(0.5) = 1830.5$

Therefore ,$Var(X) = 1830.5 - 40^2 = 230.5 $

Knowing the variance and mean, How do I do the next part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key question to ask is, if you knew in advance how many batteries were of each type, how would you model the resulting distribution of the total lifetime?

In other words, suppose you were able to tell that $Y$ batteries were of type $A$, and $40 - Y$ batteries were of type B.  Then you could number the batteries so that $$T_1, \ldots, T_Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_A = 50, \sigma_A = 15)$$ represent the random lifetimes of the Type $A$ batteries, and $$T_{Y+1}, \ldots, T_{40} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_B = 30, \sigma_B = 6)$$ represent the random lifetimes of the Type $B$ batteries.  Now, because the sum of independent (but not necessarily identically distributed) normal distributions is itself normal, we can model the total random lifetime **conditioned** on $Y$:  $$S \mid Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu , \sigma)$$ where $$\mu = \mu_A Y + \mu_B (40-Y) = 50Y + 30(40-Y) = 20Y + 1200,$$ and $$\sigma^2 = \sigma_A^2 Y + \sigma_B^2 (40-Y) = 225 Y + 36(40-Y) = 189Y + 1440.$$  Note that the **variance** is additive, not the standard deviations themselves.  So the **conditional probability** that the total lifetime of all $40$ batteries is more than $1700$, given that $Y$ batteries are of type $A$, is $$\Pr[S > 1700 \mid Y] = \ldots.$$  Then the **unconditional** (marginal) probability is computed as $$\Pr[S > 1700] = \sum_{y=0}^{40} \Pr[S > 1700 \mid Y = y] \Pr[Y = y],$$ where $$Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 40, p = 1/2).$$  This computation will give an exact result, not an approximation.  I leave it to you to continue this line of reasoning, and apply the appropriate approximation(s) if needed, to obtain a result.

Comment: In the question it was nowhere mentioned that the lifetime of the batteries follow normal distribution. Then why are you assuming them to be be normally distributed?